# Error when checking if two strings are the same in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check if two strings are the same, the first string I get from a Pastebin RAW, and the second I have saved in my assets folder in my project. The text is exactly the same, but when I try to check if they are the same with

```
if(total.toString().equals(result)){
   display.setText(
      "The two files are the same \n Log.txt: " + total.toString() +
      "\n Pastebin: " + result);
} else if(total.toString()!=result) {
   display.setText(
      "The two files arent the same \n Log.txt: " + total.toString() +
      "\n Pastebin: " + result);
```

It goes straight to my else if and displays that, I have tried deleting the file and making new Pastebins.

The full code I use is this

```
   InputStream is = getAssets().open("Log.txt");
   BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
   }
   // Loads the text from the pastebin into the string result
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("Pastebin url");
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
   String result = "";
   BufferedReader reader =
      new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));
   String line1 = null;
   while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null){
      result += line1 + "\n";
   }
   // Checks if the pastebin and Log.txt contains the same information
   if( total.toString().equals(result)){
      display.setText(
         "The two files are the same \n Log.txt: " + total.toString() +
         "\n Pastebin: " + result);
   } else if(total.toString()!=result) {
      display.setText(
         "The two files arent the same \n Log.txt: " + total.toString() +
         "\n Pastebin: " + result); 
   }
```

So can anybody tell me what I have done wrong here since it says that it isn't the same?

Comment: `else if(total.toString()!=result)` should be just `else`.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is not duplicated, The OP used `equals()` but he has a mistake in the else-statement.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Not consistently. Note `if(total.toString()!=result)`

Comment: @JonSkeet But it is not the cause of the inequality. The OP misses a new-line character `\n` within `line`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Right - I saw that there was "at least one equality bug" and incorrectly decided it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at these lines:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
```

you forget the new line character `\n`:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line + "\n");
}
```

as what you did in `result`:

```
while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null){
    result += line1 + "\n";
}
```

---

Also, note that

```
else if(total.toString()!=result)
```

should be just

```
else
```